# ajax call after x characters

Tags: ajax, jquery

I have an ajax call triggering on the maxlength of an input. However, it continues to trigger if a user continues to enter characters (because they count as a keypress). Is there any way to prevent additional ajax calls after the 5 character limit?

html

```
<input type="text" value="" id="billZipCode" name="billZipCode" class="smallInput coreAddrBill" maxlength="5">
```

javascript

```
//show city/state on input maxlength
$("input#billZipCode").live("keyup", function( event ){
    if(this.value.length == this.getAttribute('maxlength')) {
        if ($(this).valid() == true ) {
            zipLookup(this, "USA");

        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Please never write `== true`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set a `.data` attribute on the field:

```
//show city/state on input maxlength
$("input#billZipCode").live("keyup", function( event ){

    if(this.value.length == this.getAttribute('maxlength')) {
        if(!$(this).data('triggered')) {
            // set the 'triggered' data attribute to true
            $(this).data('triggered',true); 
            if ($(this).valid() == true ) { zipLookup(this, "USA"); } 
        }
    } else { $(this).data('triggered',false); }

});
```

Move the assignment inside the second `if` statement if you want to keep running this until the zipcode is valid.

Comment: I'd also suggest unsetting the attribute if the length drops below the max so it will do a lookup if someone enters another value

Comment: getting "invalid assignment left hand side" error with this function.

Comment: jsLint - bad assignment: ` $(this).data('triggered') = true; `

Comment: My bad, that should be `$(this).data('triggered',true); I'll update.

Comment: jQuery .live() has been removed in version 1.9 onwards. Replace it by on(event...

Answer (score 0):

Use a boolean variable to know if a call has already been triggered (init it to false, assert it is still false before making a call, and set it to true when you make the call).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var ready = true;
$("input#billZipCode").on("keyup", function( event ){
    if(this.value.length == this.getAttribute('maxlength')) {
        if ($(this).valid() && ready) {
            zipLookup(this, "USA");
            ready = false;  
        }
    }
});
```